# I was deported from the UK in 2010, after spending 8 months in prison, can I go back now in 2024?

Tags: united-kingdom, family

I was deported from the UK in 2010, after spending 8 months in prison, now in 2024 I would like to go back to the UK for studying with my family? Can I go back to the UK?

Comment: Which visa did you have when you were deported? You said you wanted to go to UK to study with the family. Is your family already in the UK? This is very ambiguous statement. Can you clarify?

Comment: No. A deportation order remains in force until either:
(a) it is revoked; or
(b) it has been quashed by a court or tribunal. 
Until you have successfully applied for a) revocation of your deportation order and b) entry clearance ie a visa, you cannot go back to the UK. See [Section 4](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-13-deportation)

Comment: Thank you for your response, my first visa was Student visa.

Comment: I have red about the deportation from the UK, after I have been in prison for 8 months, it says that I will be banned 10 years from travelling to the UK. Deportation was in 2010, and now it is 2024, so 10 years banned is gone, is there any chance to apply for the visa again, and what will happen if I went to the UK illegally because I can not stay in my country anymore.

Comment: To enter the UK *legally*, you **first have to apply to have your deportation order revoked**. If your application is successful, you will be eligible to apply for a visa. You will not get a visa unless you can prove that you meet the relevant requirements. Entering the UK *illegally* (in breach of the deportation order) is a [criminal offence](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/media/5a7c753e40f0b62aff6c1ced/sponsorguideappBfrom060412.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

According to the statement on the UK Immigration website “ A deportation order invalidates any permission to enter or stay in the UK and **prevents the person from returning to the UK while the deportation order is in force**.”

Normally in your deportation order, your deportation period is mentioned and you’re not allowed to apply or enter in the country during that period. According to the UK immigration website, there’s no such thing like lifetime ban so based on your prison period and ban period in your deportation order, different rules are applied. Read [here](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-13-deportation) for more details to find out which rule/clause applies in your case.

Good Luck!

Comment: It needs to be said that even when you are technically allowed to visit the UK after any ban, that doesn't mean you will be granted a visa.

Comment: I’m not sure this answer is correct. [ECB4.3.1](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/who-needs-an-entry-clearance-ecb04/ecb04-who-needs-an-entry-clearance) says *An application for entry clearance from a person with an extant Deportation Order will be refused automatically.* The OP should read the [grounds for refusal rules](https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/general-grounds-for-refusal-modernised-guidance)

Comment: @Traveller doesn't 'extant' mean 'still in force'?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes. Also from ECB4.3.1 *An applicant who has previously been deported from the UK at any time must apply in writing for a revocation of the Deportation Order and wait for the outcome of the revocation request before they can travel to the UK (if a non-visa national) or before applying for an entry clearance (if a visa national)*. The OP’s deportation order is therefore still extant.